# sendmsg() scatter-gather coroutine awaiter, optimized suspending

Tags: c++, networking, c++23, coroutines

My attempt at an `Awaiter` for sending scatter-gather data over an open file descriptor. Tested only on gcc-13.1.1

Micro-optimizing by suspending the coroutine only when actually needed. No perf measurements done. I hope to build on this to create a `write_all` coroutine.

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>
#include <expected>
#include <span>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

template <std::same_as<std::span<char>> ...Args>
class WriteAwaiter{
public:
    WriteAwaiter(int fd, std::span<char>&& arg1, Args&&... args):m_fd(fd){
    // Keeping only "pointers" to the data should be enough, as the awaiting coroutine is responsible for keeping the data valid until it is written
        std::initializer_list<std::span<char>> list{arg1, args...};
        const auto zip = std::ranges::views::zip( list, m_data);
        for (const auto &l : zip ){
            struct iovec &iov = std::get<1>(l);
            auto &data = std::get<0>(l);
            iov.iov_base = data.data();
            iov.iov_len = data.size();
        }
    }
    bool await_ready(){
        return ( m_written = send_int());
    }
    
    std::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h){
        // HACK to test suspend of awaiter without actually needing the poll() machinery
        return h; // This simulates a single call, resuming h immediately
    }
    
    std::expected<int, int> await_resume(){
        if (!m_written){
            send_int();
        }
        // m_ret must be populated. If we were resumed by POLLOUT, EAGAIN is impossible?
        return m_ret;
    }
    
private:
    
    bool send_int(){
        const struct msghdr msg{
            .msg_name = nullptr,
            .msg_namelen = 0,
            .msg_iov = m_data.data(),
            .msg_iovlen = m_data.size(),
            .msg_control = nullptr,
            .msg_controllen = 0,
            .msg_flags = 0
        };
        int r = sendmsg(m_fd, &msg, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if (r < 0 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)){
            return false;
        }
        if (r < 0){
            m_ret = std::unexpected(errno);
        } else {
            m_ret = r;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    bool m_written = false;
    std::expected<int, int> m_ret;
    std::array<struct iovec, sizeof...(Args) + 1> m_data{}; // +1 because one span is mandatory
    int m_fd = -1;
};

template<std::same_as<std::span<char>> ...Args>
WriteAwaiter<Args...> send_aw(int fd, std::span<char> &&arg1, Args&& ...args){
    return WriteAwaiter(fd, std::move(arg1), std::move(args)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
class Coroutine {
public:
    struct promise_type{
        Coroutine get_return_object(){ return Coroutine{};}
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept {return {};}
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {};}
        void return_void(){;}
        void unhandled_exception(){
            auto exc = std::current_exception();
            std::rethrow_exception(exc);
        };
    };
};

// minimal coroutine object, gets a connected descriptor
Coroutine run(fd){
    std::string s1("hello");
    std::string s2("world");
    // Example call, missing logic while(*written != s1.size() + s2.size()){ send_aw() ;} ...
    auto written = co_await send_aw(fd, 
                                std::span(s1.begin(), s1.end()), 
                                std::span(s2.begin(), s2.end()));
    if (!written){
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to send: ") + std::strerror(written.error()));
    }

int main(){
    int sv[2];
    int r = socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv);
    if (r != 0){
        std::cout << "socketpair failure " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    auto coro = run(sv[1]);
    sleep(10) ; // let coroutine do its thing
}
```

Ideas welcome on how to allow optional passing of options for `msg_control`, but that is out of scope for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simplify your code

Parts of your code are more verbose than necessary, especially when using newer C++ versions. For example, I would write:

```
template<std::same_as<std::span<char>> ...Args>
requires (sizeof...(Args) >= 1)
class WriteAwaiter {
public:
    WriteAwaiter(int fd, Args&&... args): m_fd(fd) {
        std::initializer_list list{args...};
        for (auto& [data, iov]: std::ranges::views::zip(list, m_data)) {
            iov = {
                .iov_base = data.data(),
                .iov_len = data.size(),
            };
        }
    }
    …
    std::array<iovec, sizeof...(Args)> m_data;
};


template<typename ...Args>
auto send_aw(int fd, Args&& ...args){
    return WriteAwaiter(fd, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

By using the `requires` clause to check that we have the right number of arguments, I don't need to check it in the constructor, and declaring `m_data` looks much simpler now, no need for a comment to explain where the `+ 1` comes from.

Using structured bindings we don't need to call `std::get<>()`, and since C++20 we can use designated initializers as well.

For `send_aw()` you don't have to repeat all the constraints you added to `WriteAwaiter`. Just forward everything as is (using proper perfect forwarding), `WriteAwaiter` itself will complain if it was not correct. The drawback is that the error message from incorrect use of `send_aw()` might not be as nice; one solution would be to move the constraints to `send_aw()` instead, if you don't expect any caller to construct `WriteAwaiter`s directly themselves.

## `WriteAwaiter`'s constructor only takes temporaries

Because of the way you wrote the constraint that all `Args` should be `std::span<char>`, the code does not work if you pass in an l-value:

```
std::string str("Hello, world!\n");
std::span arg(str);
write_aw(fd, arg);
```

This is because `Args` will then be deduced to `std::span<char>&`, not `std::span<char>`. One fix would be to remove the reference from `Args` before checking it:

```
template<typename ...Args>
requires (std::same_as<std::remove_reference_t<Args>, std::span<char>> && ...)
…
```

But even better is to see that it doesn't really matter what the exact type is, as long as you can construct a `std::initializer_list<std::span<char>>` from the arguments. So as long as it is [convertible to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) a `std::span<char>` it should be fine:

```
template<std::convertible_to<std::span<char>> ...Args>
…
```

This now has the added benefit that you can write:

```
std::string str("Hello, world!\n");
write_aw(fd, str);
```

Since a `std::string` is implicitly convertible to a `std::span<char>`.

Another solution would be to not make it a template, but rather to take a `std::initializer_list<std::span<char>>` as a parameter:

```
class WriteAwaiter {
public:
    WriteAwaiter(int fd, std::initializer_list<std::span<char>> args): m_fd(fd) {
        for (auto& data: args) {
            m_data.push_back(iovec{
                .iov_base = data.data(),
                .iov_len = data.size(),
            });
        }
    }
    …
    std::vector<iovec> m_data;
};
```

The drawback of that is the need to use braces when calling it, and the fact that its size is not known at compile time.

## Allow zero args

As @Deduplicator mentioned, the code still works fine even if `sizeof...(Args) == 0`. While it is a corner case with little use, it's better to just allow it; nothing will break, and the behavior of sending zero bytes in this case is very reasonable.

## Miscellaneous issues

- [Prefer `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n).
- Send error messages to `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout`.
- Prefer standard C++ functions over C or POSIX functions, for example use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead of the POSIX `sleep()` function.

Comment: Is there a case for using a `std::assignable_to` constraint instead of a `std::same_as` constraint, to fix the problem of passing lvalues?

Comment: I think you mean [`std::assignable_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/assignable_from)? It is a bit heavyweight since it specifically tests `operator=()`), which might not be necessary? Perhaps [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) would be best?

Comment: Yes, `std::convertible_to` sounds better.  I never quite know which to use.

Comment: Disallowing zero is the bane of generic code. Even though zero leads to trivial code, it should still work, maybe even optimized.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree. Although it does not make sense to send zero bytes on a `SOCK_STREAM` socket, there is also no harm in doing that.

Comment: @Deduplicator you can still pass a zero-length data span. Effectively sending 0 bytes. Perhaps slightly less elegant than send with no parameters, but the possibility is there. I agree that the cost of allowing it is pretty much 0.

Comment: @serafean Yes, there are always ways to adapt an unfortunate interface, though they may be cumbersome and/or inefficient. If there is a choice though, better fix the interface. Those warts propagate if not explicitly fixed, especially in generic code.